# Use AD5933 evaluation board for impedance calculation 1Khz-100kHz

Tags: impedance, dielectric

I recently got the AD5933EBZ evaluation board. After taking a look at the user guide, the AN1252 application note and the datasheet of AD5933 itself, I am trying to measure the capacitance across a capacitor that I have made. I'm using a feedback resistor (RFB)  = 714kOhm and a R(calibration) = 1.4MOhm. I have made a capacitor by sticking 2 copper plates to the back of a teflon backplate and then adjusted them such that the copper plates are 9cmx9cm and 40 mm apart. So, by calculation, it should give a capacitance of 1.79pF ==> Which should give me an impedance of 1.6MOhm at 30kHz.

[image: Capacitor that I made]

However, when I check the value obtained, it shows 1.2MOhm ==> Which is nearly 4.2pF. I need to get an accurate value of capacitance since later on I will "disturb" the dielectric in between the 2 plates and observe the change of permittivity.

Comment: And your actual question is?

Comment: You got a nice oscilloscope. You surely can afford an LC200-A L/C meter from ebay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have a very good situation for using the simple parallel plate capacitor formula and expecting accuracy.

The equation ignores edge effects and you have slabs of acrylic or polycarbonate (I don't see any teflon there) with \$\epsilon_R\$ which could be as much as 4. There is also stray capacitance between your wires. And goodness knows what that work surface right by the plates is doing to your readings. A few pF is not a large capacitance.

The formula is more accurate when the space between the plates is very small compared to the dimensions of the plates.

You can put the copper plates in the middle of much bigger pieces with low dielectric constant such as FR-3703 PU foam, making the edges of the copper far from any other object. And keep the wire length down, keep them better separated and held in position.

But you're likely still not going to be able to predict the capacitance to a high precision without using field solver software, and even then you would want to confirm with a precision measurement using good test equipment. The situation is too complex. It's possible to calculate capacitor values to high precision from first principles if they are made in an enclosed fashion, and standards agencies do that, but that is not your situation.

Maybe if you look at what is actually going on (think about electric field lines between the plates, bulging out, taking paths through the plastic, table and between the wires etc.) you can model the situation as a fixed capacitance in parallel with a variable capacitance, and determine the ratio. Right now the setup is very messy.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. So, if I use FR-3703 foam and hold the wires in place, I would reduce stray capacitances right? Also, I ran the same setup on a Solartron and it shows a capacitance of 3.2pF. So yes, I understand there will be additional capacitances, but if I'm aware of this, I can take it into account in my code. And what do you mean "making the edges of the copper far from any other object " ?

Comment: Keeping both the copper plates well separated from things like the table, your hands, test equipment etc. Consider a largish grounded Faraday cage around the whole apparatus (metal, metal screen or whatever)